# Marking tests in ExUnit as pending

Tags: elixir, tdd, ex-unit

I am looking for a way to mark tests written in ExUnit as pending.

I know I can skip tests by a tag, but I am looking for a way to skip tests in a way that makes it highly transparent that these tests have been skipped because they need to be implemented. Other test frameworks like RSpec or ESpec show these marked as yellow and highlight them on every run.

Is there such a feature in ExUnit?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this with ExUnit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you could leverage following:

```
pcregrep -hM "@tag :to_be_implemented\s*test" ./test/**/*.exs | grep test
```

and potentially create your own `mix task`

Answer (score 2):

```
@tag :skip
test "this is my pending test"
```

This will result in:

```
 mix test
 .......................................................**

 Finished in 0.1 seconds (0.00s async, 0.1s sync)
 57 tests, 0 failures, 2 skipped
```